# Generate wordlist using non-default rules (John The Ripper)

Tags: hash, password-cracking, tools

If I want to create a wordlist, using JTR to mangle a source list by applying its default rules to them I can do this like so:

```
# john -rules --stdout --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt | head
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
123456
12345
123456789
password
iloveyou
princess
1234567
rockyou
12345678
abc123
```

However, if I want to apply non-default rules to the wordlist, John doesn't like it:

```
# john --rules=Jumbo --stdout --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt | head
Extra parameter for option: "--rules=Jumbo"
```

This ruleset works fine when cracking hashes:

```
john hashes.txt --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt --rules=Jumbo
```

Why can't John apply the rules to the wordlist and output a list rather than only being able to crack using a rulesset such as Jumbo?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and it works fine for me.  Make sure you have a new JtR.  I'm using 1.8.0-jumbo

sample output:

```
./john -rules:Jumbo -w:password.lst --stdout | head 
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
123456789
password
```

Comment: Could you post your sample output? Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89083)

Comment: Can I do preformated output in comments?

Comment: @Xander: Now that it includes sample output, I'd say this was an acceptable answer. Previously though, I'd agree and say it was more appropriate for a comment.

Comment: @Marcin - Just tried it again and it appears to be working. Even the exact syntax I posted above in my question now works. Confusing indeed. I'm using 1.8.0-jumbo as before.